# SUBSTRING_INDEX com REGEX

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, regex

Tem como eu fazer uma pesquisa do último nome de uma pessoas porém com expressão regular?

Hoje eu uso o  `SUBSTRING_INDEX` para pegar o **último nome**, mais quero pegar partes desse **último nome**, quando vou  pesquisar por nome ou fragmentos de nome  de pessoas estou usando o **REGEXP** que chama uma função minha que cria um expressão regular.
Quando tento usar o `SUBSTRING_INDEX` com o `REGEXP` parasse não não da muito certo não.

**Uso o cakePHP para desenvolver.**

A linha de comando abaixo:

```
 $filtros = array_merge($filtros, array("SUBSTRING_INDEX(Usuario.nome, ' ', 1) = 'REGEXP \"".$this->stringParaBusca($criterios["criteriaPrimeiroNome"])."\"'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `REGEXP` retorna `1` se encontrar algo, e `0` se não encontrar. Portanto nesse caso você não pode usar o comparador `=`, precisa alterar a query assim:

```
... WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Usuario.nome, ' ', 1) REGEXP 'sua_regex'
```

Comment: Consegui resolver, foi só tirar o "=" mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: @JeremiasPereira aceite a reposta do nosso colega então...